# Laravel Eloquent Relationships - Two different delivery addresses associated with one order model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have two different delivery addresses for each order:

- Invoice Address
- Delivery Address

Both of those have the same fields, so I created only one `Address` model for them.

Models:

- Address
- Order

Each order contains two fields:

- invoice_address
- delivery_address

I want each of those fields to point either to the same address (in case the user wants the goods shipped to the invoice address) or to two different addresses (in case the delivery address is different from the invoice address).

**How would I go about creating relationships for this purpose?**

Here's what I've tried:

Order.php

```
public function orderAddress() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}

public function deliveryAddress() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

Address.php

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to assign two different addresses to one order.

I thought about using the `hasMany()` relationship but then it will be hard to tell which address is which without specifying a type in the `Address` model.

Comment: Have you try `Polymorphic Relations` on this scenario? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** In the `Order` model:

```
public function orderAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'invoice_address');
}

public function deliveryAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'delivery_address');
}
```

In the `Address` model:

```
public function orderForInvoiceAddress()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'invoice_address');
}

public function orderForDeliveryddress()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'delivery_address');
}
```

**2.** But I think a better way to handle this is to use one standard foreign key `order_id` and add `type` column:

```
public function orderAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address')->where('type', 1);
}

public function deliveryAddress()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address')->where('type', 2);
}
```

And in `Address` model:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

Comment: Will this not create a problem when an address is only a delivery address? It will leave the invoice_address field empty. Should I make those nullable?

Comment: @Pe-Ter yes, you should make these `nullable` and check if it's `null`.